# Using two Arduino dimmer's on two lamps using one eletrical grid

Tags: arduino, dimmer

I'm following a tutorial to build [this](http://www.inmojo.com/store/inmojo-market/item/digital-ac-dimmer-module/) dimmer module. After testing it with a lamp, everything worked well. Then I tried to move forward, making two dimmer modules to control two lamps.

I'm making all tests at my house, i.e., the same eletrical grid is shared by all wall plug and therefore both dimmers and lamps are working at it.

Then, the problem: If I connect one lamp at a time on the power, everything works well. But then, If I plug both lamps at the same time, things start to get weird. One lamp turns ON and OFF at a high frequency and the other one doesn't work.

I'm using all of these with an Android mobile, through a Bluetooh module.

And my questions:

a) If there a problem to use two dimmers on the same eletrical grid (I feel that the circuit loose the synchronism with the grid when both lamps are plugged)?

b) Can an Arduino control two dimmers at once (code below, which I'm using).

Thank you,

```
int result;

int AC_LOAD = 4;
int AC_LOAD2 = 5;

int dimming = 125;
int dimming2 = 125;

char incomingByte;

String numberReceivedInStringFormat = "";
int numberReceivedInIntFormat = 10;
int lastValidNumber = 10;
boolean notUsed = false;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(AC_LOAD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AC_LOAD2, OUTPUT);

  attachInterrupt(0, zero_crosss_int, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(1, zero_crosss_int2, RISING);

}

void zero_crosss_int() {
  int dimtime = (65 * dimming);
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(8.33);
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);/
}

void zero_crosss_int2() {
  int dimtime = (65 * dimming2);
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(8.33);
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD2, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = (char) Serial.read();
    numberReceivedInStringFormat += incomingByte;
    if (Serial.available() == 0) {
      numberReceivedInIntFormat = numberReceivedInStringFormat.toInt();
    }
  }

  numberReceivedInStringFormat = "";

  if (numberReceivedInIntFormat < 10 || numberReceivedInIntFormat > 99) {
    numberReceivedInIntFormat = lastValidNumber;
  } else {
    lastValidNumber = numberReceivedInIntFormat;
  }

  result =  (int) (((-115 * numberReceivedInIntFormat) + 12275) / 89);

  dimming = result;
  dimming2 = result;

  if (notUsed) {
    delay(30);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can get unexpectedly complicated.

The way your dimmer module works by waiting for the AC power signal to cross zero volts and then turning on the power at some delay after that.

Depending on where you live and how your house is wired, the two lights you are controlling may or may not be connected to the same phase. This means they may or may not cross zero at the same time.

If you are sure that the two dimmers are on the same phase (if, for example, they are both plugged into the same outlet), then my guess as to what is happening goes something like this...

1. Both dimmers see the same zero crossing at the same moment.
2. The two zero crossing connected pins change at the same moment.
3. The pin with the higher interrupt priority triggers and interrupt.
4. The 1st interrupt handler executes. While it is executing, the 2nd handler waits.
5. The 1st interrupt handler does turn on the light at the right time and then turns it off, which takes some time.
6. The 1st interrupt handler finishes and returns.
7. The 2nd handler now gets to run, but by now things have changed. We are not at the zero crossing anymore, we are after the place in the wave where the 1st handler happened to be finished.
8. The 2nd handler runs and turns on the light at whatever place in the wave it happens to be now. This takes some time.
9. The 2nd handler returns.

You can see that wacky and timing dependent stuff can now happen.

Probably the most robust way to fix such that it will work with any outlets with any phase is to make the interrupt handlers run very quickly to minimize the amount they can interfere with each other. One way to do this would be to replace the cycle-burning delayMicroseconds() delays with timers and interrupts.

If timers and interrupts are more effort than you are willing to put into this project (they are super useful, but can take a lot of effort to get working), then you could hack something easier together if you knew that both dimmers would be on circuits with the same phase. You could have a single interrupt handler for both dimmers. This handler would figure out what sequence to turn both dimmers on and off and the delays between the steps and then control both dimmers in a single flow of execution. Make sense?

Comment: To add to that, using delays in interrupts is a really bad idea full stop. What you can do is set a flag in the interrupt (still having an ISR for each light). In the loop function you check the two flags - based on the flags getting set you can then use then using the infamous "blink without delay" approach (only with the micros() function) determine when they should be turned on/off.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I'm just not sure I know how to implement the solution. But thank you very much. I'll try that.

Comment: @bigjosh so If I use two arduinos, maybe I won't have any problem?

Comment: Two ardunios each attached to its own dimmer should be no problem. Two dimmers attached to one arduino no problem either, you just have to write a bit of code.. :)

Comment: This library could be very handy for making straightforward code to control both dimmers from one arduio....http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/